# Quero acessar um método de um webservice feito em C#

Tags: javascript, c#

Estou tentando acessar o metodo de Login de um certo webservice, mas ao invés de me retornar o o .Token que eu peço na respota, eu recebo um HTML puro do webservice

Meu código js:

```
$.ajax({

      crossDomain: "true",
      //contentType: "text/xml",
      //type: "POST",
      url: "http://macchips.macpontoweb.com.br/wsvisita/services/comum/autenticacao/autenticacaosrv.svc?Login",
      data: {

        usuario: client.value,
        senha: senha.value,

      },

      success: function(resposta){


       alert(resposta.Token);

      },

      error: function(error){
        var falha = JSON.stringify(error);

        alert("Erro " + falha);
      }

    });
```

As linhas type e contentType estão comentadas. Eu acredito que precise delas mas não sei ao certo

Estou tentando acessar o webservice via um aplicativo que estou desenvolvendo

/////EDIT///////

Fiz alguma alterações, agora estou recebendo um readyState:4, status:200, statusText:load

Meu código alterado:

```
 $.ajax({

 type: "POST",
          crossDomain: "true",
          dataType: "jsonp",
          contentType: "text/xml", 
          url: "http://macchips.macpontoweb.com.br/WSVisita/Services/Comum/Autenticacao/AutenticacaoSrv.svc",
          data: {
              Login: 'wellington, wellington'
          },

          success: function(resposta){ 

           window.location.href="login.html";

           alert(resposta);

          },

          error: function(jqxhr, error){
            var falha = JSON.stringify(error);

            alert("Erro " + falha);
          }

        });
```

Comment: 2 coisas: **1.** Você não está usando `java`, está usando `javascript`. **2.** Você já viu o que diz este HTML? Ele pode ser útil.

Comment: Além de descomentar as linhas troque a "url" para: *http://macchips.macpontoweb.com.br/wsvisita/services/comum/autenticacao/autenticacaosrv/Login*

Comment: Não funcionou, eu recebo um alerta de erro com o HTML da pagina do webservice e status 404

Comment: Sim, ele é o html da página do webservice

Comment: no link que te mandei faltou a extensão ".svc", com ela funciona?

Comment: Ainda não funciona, mas agora estou recebendo um erro status 400, bad request

Comment: o WebService foi feito por você? Ele foi projetado para receber requisições de outros domínios?

Comment: Não foi feito por mim, mas foi projetado pra isso, então acredito que tenha todas as autorizaçoes necessárias